# Put style tag in php echo

Tags: php, html, css, yii, styles

Is it possible to put `<style>` tag inside and `echo`? My scenario is that I have a table of reimbursements and there's this "Type" column, where if the type is an "Ad Hoc Reimbursement", the whole table `<tr>`'s text color and font style will be changed:

[image]

And here's what it should look like:
[image]

I am using Yii 2.0 php framework. Here's my code:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'], 
        [
            'header' => 'Employee ID',
            'value' => 'employeeId'
        ],
        [
            'header' => 'Identification <br> Number',
            'value' => 'IDnumber'
        ],
        [
            'header' => 'Employee <br> Name',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => 'fullName'
        ],
        [
            'header' => 'Attachment',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                 return !empty($model->attachment) ? Html::img($model->getImageUrl(), ['class' => 'reim-attach']): 'No Attachment';
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'receipt_company',
            'header' => 'Merchant',
        ],
        'description',
        [
            'attribute' => 'date',
            'header' => 'Date <br><span style= "color:gray;font-size:8pt;"> (dd-mm-yyyy)</span>',
        ],
        'currency',
        [
            'attribute' => 'amount',
            'format'=>['decimal',2],
            'value' => function ($model){ 
                return !empty($model['amount']) ? $model['amount'] : 0.00;
            }
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'exchange_rate',
            'header' => 'Exchange <br> Rate',
            'format'=>['decimal',2],
            'value' => function ($model){ 
                return !empty($model['exchange_rate']) ? $model['exchange_rate'] : 0.00;
            }
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'converted_amount',
            'header' => 'Converted <br> Amount',
            'format'=>['decimal',2],
            'value' => function ($model){ 
                return !empty($model['converted_amount']) ? $model['converted_amount'] : 0.00;
            }
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'chargeable',
            'header' => 'Chargeable to <br> Client',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model['chargeable'] ? 'Chargeable' : 'Non-chargeable';
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'date_noted',
            'header' => 'Date Modified <br><span style= "color:gray;font-size:8pt;"> (dd-mm-yyyy)</span>',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'label' => 'Status',
            'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                if ($model['status'] == "Pending") {
                    return Html::button('Pending', ['class' => 'status-pending']);
                } elseif ($model['status'] == "Draft") {
                    return Html::button('Draft', ['class' => 'status-draft']);
                } elseif ($model['status'] == "Approved") {
                    return Html::button('Approved', ['class' => 'status-approved']);
                } elseif ($model['status'] == "Rejected") {
                    return Html::button('Rejected', ['class' => 'status-rejected']);
                } elseif ($model['status'] == "Reimbursed") {
                    return Html::button('Reimbursed', ['class' => 'status-reimbursed']);
                }
            }
        ],
        'type',
        [
            'label' => 'Action',
            'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                if($model['status'] == "Pending") {
                    return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'View'])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Approve', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'approve(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Approve'])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Reject', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'reject(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Reject']);
                }  elseif ($model['status'] == "Draft") {
                    return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'View'])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    . Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['update']).'&id=' . (string)$model->_id, 'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton3', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'Update'])
                    .'&nbsp'
                    . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', ['delete', 'id' => (string)$model->_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-responsive','data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'Delete', 'data' => ['confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this reimbursement?', 'method' => 'post']]);
                } elseif ($model['status'] == "Approved")  {
                    if ($model->type == 'Ad Hoc Reimbursement') {
                        return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'View'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Reimburse', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-responsive', 'onclick'=>'reimburse(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Reimburse']);
                    } else {
                        return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'View'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Approve', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'approve(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'disabled' => true, 'title'=>'Approve'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Reject', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'reject(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'disabled' => true, 'title'=>'Reject']);
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($model->type == 'Ad Hoc Reimbursement') {
                        echo "<style>.table-striped > tbody > tr { font-style: italic !important;color: #259A5A !important; }</style>";
                        return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'View'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Reimburse', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'reimburse(value)', 'disabled' => true, 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','title'=>'Reimburse']);
                    } else {
                        return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['value' => Url::to(['view']).'&id=' . (string)$model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-view btn-responsive','id' => 'modalButton2', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'title'=>'View'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"></i> Approve', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'approve(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'disabled' => true, 'title'=>'Approve'])
                        .'&nbsp'
                        .Html::button('<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Reject', ['value' =>  $model['_id'], 'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-responsive disable', 'onclick'=>'reject(value)', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 'disabled' => true, 'title'=>'Reject']);
                    }                
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
]);
```

In the last part, you can see the `if ($model->type == 'Ad Hoc Reimbursement')` and inside it, I put `echo "<style>.table-striped > tbody > tr { font-style: italic !important;color: #259A5A !important; }</style>";` which I think is not right since it's NOT working.

Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: I think your style isn't correct or is being overridden.  Try opening chrome developer tools with that page and create that style value to see if it actually affects anything.  Play around until you can get that effect, copy that style and then echo what works in your code.  Also try placing it at the end of your returned string as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying conditional styling within your column configuration, which isn't going to work.

What you want to do is define the styling as a class, and conditionally change the row class in the `<tr>`

```
echo GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'rowOptions' => function ($model, $index, $widget, $grid){
    return ['class'=> ($model->type == 'Ad Hoc Reimbursement') ? 'ad-hoc-reimbursement' : null];
  },
]);

<style> 
  tr.ad-hoc-reimbursement {font-style: italic !important;color: #259A5A !important; }
</style>
```